# Unable to obtain command return value in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have the following script:

```
        serverip=$1
        key=$2
        linenumber=0
        ##CHeck If server IP exists
        if grep -wq $serverip server; then
                echo "IP exists"
                linenumber=`awk '$0 ~ "$serverip" {print NR}' file`
                echo "$linenumber"
        fi
```

The file contains:

```
192.168.18.2       testing123      3

./radius_adt.sh 192.168.18.2 nevis
```

Does not print the line number.

The awk command works outside the script.

```
awk '$0 ~ "192.168.18.4" {print NR}' file

output: 1
```

WHy is the command does not run inside the script and its return value copied into linenumber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
linenumber=`awk '$0 ~ "$serverip" {print NR}' file`
```

And `shell` won't be able to expand `$serverip` inside single quotes and awk will treat it literally. You should use it like this to pass shell variable to awk:

```
linenumber=$(awk -v serverip="$serverip" '$0 ~ serverip {print NR}' file)
```